# Java "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[][] to int" when returning copied array

Tags: java, arrays, variables

I wanted to make function that returns a copied array, but I'm getting this error:

> ```
> "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[][] to int" on line 10,
> ```

and I don't know what is wrong.

```java
public class Usun {

    public int newTable(int[] table[]) {
        int[] newTable[];
        for (int i = 0; i <= table.length; i++)  {
            newTable[i] = table[i];  
        }         
        return newTable;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this? `int[] table[]` Please write `int[][] table`, that's more usual.

Comment: Btw. you can call [`Object#clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) on arrays for cloning, which comes in handy here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to return an array of int (`int[]`) not an int, also for declaring an array of int you use `int[] table` and not `int[] table[]`

also, as @small_ticket mentioned in his comment, you have to initialize your array, or you will get `NullPointerException` because you'll be trying to add elements to an uninitialized array, which results in compile time errors.

```
public class usun {
    public int[] newTable(int[] table) {

       int[] newTable = new int[table.length];
       for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)  {
          newTable[i] = table[i];  
       }         
       return newTable;
   }
}
```

Comment: You have to initialize newTable

Comment: Additionally, the array is not ``null``. It is uninitialized. If you would access it with a ``null``, it would give a NPE as you said, but in this case, it wouldn't even compile, because it is a compile error, not a runtime error.

Answer (score -1):

`newTable` is an 2 dimensional array. You try to return this array in your method with a return type of `int`.

Change the return type of your function to `int[][]`. Also, `newTable` is not properly initialized in your code.

In addition, you can use built-in methods like `Arrays#copyOf` and so on for array deep copying as you don't have to write them yourself.

Comment: The initial requirement was `I wanted to make function that returns a copied array`. So neither of your bullet points answer the question.

Comment: @Aserre This is wrong. ``Arrays#copyOf`` does exactly that. Also my point 1. explains how to fix his code in addition to my additional comment after that. So I answered the complete question and provided additional information. Edit: I fixed the layout, so you can see the relevant points, that definetly answer the question.